# Javascript pictures in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a slideshow with bullets underneath it, and when i click them, i can go to the coresponding picture. The problem is, if you click a lot, the pictures change position with the bullets, and the javascript aksk pictures that doesn't excist. Can someone take a look at it and maybe see what's wrong with my code? http://users.telenet.be/Cedric.Cornelis/V2/
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: works fine for me - Safari, OSX 10.6

Comment: Likewise, works fine for me in Chrome, no matter how often I click. What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue in Firefox. Can you isolate the slider in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and show the relevant code in your question?